# Difference between macros with and without using do ... while

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do-While and if-else statements in C/C++ macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)

I have the following macros :

```
#define FREE1(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0)
#define FREE2(x) free(x); x = NULL
```

What is the difference between these macros?

Comment: ... One contains a `do`/`while` loop...

Comment: Note: `FREE1` contains a terminating semicolon that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following example

```
if (some_test) FREE2(x);
```

expands to

```
if (some_test)
    free(x);
x = NULL; // happens regardless of value of some_test
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be more satisfying to figure this one out yourself.

Hint:

```
if(y) FREE2(x);
```