# What is the reason for error while returning a structure in this C program?

Tags: c, syntax, struct

My program intends to achieve this

**(A)** Write a C function named `larger()` that returns the later date of any two dates passed to it. For example, if the dates 10/9/2001 and 11/3/2001 are passed to `larger()`, the second date would be returned.

**(B)** Create the larger() function that was written for (A) in a complete unit. Store the date structure returned by larger() in a separate date structure and display the member values of the returned data structure.

I am working on this problem for my C Language course.  I had everything going well (I thought), except that I kept getting "The larger date is: 0/0/0" no matter what I entered. So I started tinkering, and now I cannot get rid of the syntax error, or figure out my 0/0/0 problem. Obviously the dates aren't making it back through.  I'm still pretty new at this (and very new at structs), so any help would be awesome!

The line that's giving me the syntax error is near the bottom of main():

```
DATES result[NUM] = larger(DATES user[NUM]);
```

The code in full:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 2
struct Dates
{
       int month;
       int day;
       int year;
};
typedef struct Dates DATES;
DATES larger(DATES[NUM]);
DATES more;
int main()
{
    DATES user[NUM];

    printf("You will enter two dates, and the program will return the larger.\n");
    while (user[0].month < 1 || user[0].month > 12)
         {printf("\nPlease enter the first month, 1-12: ");
         scanf("%d", &user[0].month);}
    while (user[0].day < 1 || user[0].day > 31)
          {printf("\nPlease enter the first day, 1-31: ");
          scanf("%d", &user[0].day);}
    while (user[0].year < 1)
          {printf("\nPlease enter the first year: ");
          scanf("%d)", &user[0].year);}
    printf("\nDate entered: %d/%d/%d.\n", user[0].month, user[0].day, user[0].year);

    while (user[1].month < 1 || user[1].month > 12)
         {printf("\nPlease enter the first month, 1-12: ");
         scanf("%d", &user[1].month);}
    while (user[1].day < 1 || user[1].day > 31)
          {printf("\nPlease enter the first day, 1-31: ");
          scanf("%d", &user[1].day);}
    while (user[1].year < 1)
          {printf("\nPlease enter the first year: ");
          scanf("%d)", &user[1].year);}
    printf("\nDate entered: %d/%d/%d.\n\n", user[1].month, user[1].day, user[1].year);

    DATES result[NUM] = larger(DATES user[NUM]);  /* Problem here */

    printf("The larger date is %d/%d/%d.\n\n", result[0].month, result[0].day, result[0].year);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

DATES larger(DATES more[NUM])
{        
      int days0;
      int days1;

      days0 = (more[0].month*31)+(more[0].day)+(more[0].year*365);
      days1 = (more[1].month*31)+(more[1].day)+(more[1].year*365);

      if (days1 > days0)
         {more[0] = more[1];}

return (more[0]);
}
```

Comment: Even though it seems like a homework question, it's an interesting one and I liked it that you tried to work it out yourself first, on your own.Errors do happen, but it's always good to try on one's own first!!

Comment: And edit out the **JERK** part from my code if you intend to submit this code to someone!!

Comment: I note that the algorithm for determining which date is later is flawed. As a concrete example, consider the comparison of 2000-12-31 and 2001-01-01. The days value for 2000-12-31 is 31+(12*31)+(2000*365) = 730403, but the days value for 2001-01-01 is 1+(1*31)+(2001*365) = 730397. Yet I'd swear New Year's Eve of one year comes before New Year's Day of the next year. If you use `(month-1)*31` instead of `month*31` and use 12*31 = 372 (or a larger number) in place of 365, you should be safe (because 31+((12-1)*31)+(2000*372) = 744372 is less than 1+((1-1)*31)+(2001*372) = 744373).

Answer (score 1):

```
DATES result[NUM] = larger(DATES user[NUM]);
```

What's this intended to do? `DATES result[NUM]` declares an array of `DATES`. (But each `DATES` contains only one date, which is confusing.) But despite being an array, it's initialized with a single object, the return value from `larger`. The argument to `larger`, `DATES user[NUM]`, appears to be declaring `user`, a variable which already exists. It looks like you're trying to clarify to the compiler that `user` is an array of dates, but `DATES` doesn't go there and `[NUM]` appears to be indexing into the array, which you don't want.

Probably what you want is

```
DATES result = larger( user );
```

Also there are some serious style issues which will cause trouble later:

- Array types for function parameters as in `DATES larger(DATES[NUM]);` are converted to pointers. On that line, `NUM` does nothing and the declaration is the same as `DATES larger( DATES * );`. Despite what some teachers may say, pointers and arrays are not the same thing. When the distinction is important, this style causes confusion. Use `DATES larger( DATES * )` instead.
- It doesn't make sense to capitalize `DATES`. Caps usually indicate a preprocessor macro.
- Preprocessor macros are like a sledgehammer. Using them for simple numeric constants is less elegant than constructs like `const int num = 2;` or `enum { num = 2 };`
- Descriptive variable names like `input_limit` and `user_input` would be better than `num` and `user`.
- Don't rely on uninitialized data. `user[0].month` might be 6 after `user` is defined but not initialized. Always write a value before reading.
- Braces should be kept visible. Grouping braces closely with the first and last words of the loop hides them, which is good if you think they're ugly, but then it's very very easy to incorrectly add a line to the loop, producing a hard-to-debug flow control error.

Comment: Basically, the user enters two dates into a struct. That has to be sent to another function to compare them, and then return the larger date (as a struct) back to main() to display the winner.  The line in question here is my attempt at returning the struct to main() so it can be displayed.

Comment: @iMPose27 Got all that… this is the correct way of expressing it. Is there a problem?

Comment: Not a problem. I'm taking the course online, which essentially means "teach yourself using the book." The #define statement, capitalized typedef, etc., are all I've known. Your ways are new and shiny. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several little corrections needed in this program but your main problem is the difference between while and do while loops.

```
while(<condition>)
{
  //Something
}
```

and

```
do
{
  //Something
}
while(<condition>)
```

differ in the fact that do while enters the loop atleast once and then checks for the condition to be satisfied. But while on the other hand never enters the loop if the condition is not satisfied. So in a nutshell you aren't entering the while loop and hence aren't reading anything from the user.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I have switched from while to do-while.  Before the syntax error, I would get it to verify the user entries, but coming back out after the larger() function it would just result in 0/0/0.

Answer (score 0):

There are many logical and syntactical errors in your program.I corrected all the syntactical part and must point out the major flaw in the logic of the `while` loops.You seem to have confused `>` and `<` in the following conditions:

```
while (user[0].month < 1 || user[0].month > 12);  //Wrong

while (user[0].month > 1 || user[0].month < 12);  //Correct
```

Months are less than `1` or greater than `12` only in Mars,but on earth,due to pollution,they are between `1` and `12`.I have corrected those and pointed that out in comments.And you should use a `for` loop instead of repeating the same thing for each element of the array `DATES`

**AAAAAGHHH**  It was so full of errors.Here's the working version.It achieves the 2 objectives that you mentioned in your question-Ask user for 2 dates,and find which one is bigger/later.I am not including **BC**, only **AD** years.Won't matter unless you want to know if some neanderthal man was born earlier or later than any of us.And the function `larger` returns a pointer to the answer,which is stored in a new datastructure `largerdate` and printed out.

Here's a brief explanation for the revised code:

The outer `for` loop automates the input for each date.There's no need to repeat the same code for each date as you did.If the number of dates goes up,it will be tedious.Further,the `do-while` loop asks the user for the date in the range specified.If that jerk makes an error,he is yelled at and the condition of that loop makes sure the jerk has to enter again.The two dates are stored in an array `user[]` and the base address of type `DATE*` is passed as an argument to the function `larger()` which compares the two dates and returns a pointer of type `DATE*` to the larger date.This is used to store the greater date in a new datastructure called `largerdate` and then printed out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 2
struct Dates
{
       int month;
       int day;
       int year;
};
typedef struct Dates DATES;
DATES  *larger(DATES*);
//DATES more;     //Not needed as you are doing the same in function definition

int main(void)
{
    DATES user[NUM],largerdate;
    int i;
     printf("You will enter two dates, and the program will return the larger.\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)   //for loop is handy when NUM increases.
       {
           do
           {
        printf("\nPlease enter the month number %d, 1-12:\n ",i);
         scanf("%d", &user[i].month);
         if(user[i].month<1||user[i].month>12)
         printf("I told you enter a number between 1-12 JERK!!\n");
           }while(user[i].month<1||user[i].month>12);
          do
           {
        printf("\nPlease enter the day number %d, 1-31:\n ",i);
         scanf("%d", &user[i].day);
         if(user[i].day<1||user[i].day>31)
         printf("I told you enter a number between 1-31 JERK!!\n");
           }while(user[i].day<1||user[i].day>31);
           do
           {
        printf("\nPlease enter the year number %d,greater than one:\n ",i);
         scanf("%d", &user[i].year);
         if(user[i].year<1)
         printf("I told you enter a number greater than 1 JERK!!\n");
           }while(user[i].year<1);
    printf("\nDate number %d entered is: %d/%d/%d.\n", i+1,user[i].month, user[i].day, user[i].year);

   } //for loop ends.It avoids repeating the same thing for DATES[1]


   largerdate=*larger(user);
   printf("\n\nThe larger/later date is %d/%d/%d\n",largerdate.month,largerdate.day,\
   largerdate.year);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

DATES *larger(DATES *more)
{
      int days0;
      int days1;

      days0 = (more[0].month*31)+(more[0].day)+(more[0].year*365);
      days1 = (more[1].month*31)+(more[1].day)+(more[1].year*365);

      if (days1 > days0)
     return more+1;
      else
      return more;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help!  I'll take a while and consider the different choices you made in coding versus mine.  The syntax line doesn't look any different.  Does it resolve itself elsewhere?

Comment: As for the months, that was my idea of user input validation. If they entered a month value < 1 or > 12, it would force them to re-enter a value.

Comment: @iMPose27 Just a minute, let me correct the remaining part.Some lines in your code are just not needed.

Comment: @iMPose27 No no, that's faulty logic.First accept what they enter using `scanf()`, **then** check using an `if` whether the input is between 1 and 12.

Comment: @iMPose27 I've finally arrived at the correct version of the program.**It was full of errors and faulty logic**.It **raped** my mind completely.The least you could do is invite me for **steak** dinner.If you are a girl, a kiss would do.

Comment: @iMPose27 Check out the full revised program.I am posting it now.

Comment: @iMPose27 Oops, your function `larger()` is supposed to return the result.I'll tweak for that in a moment.Let me go for a bath first.15 minutes.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Nice Code but if both the dates are same it always returns the first date

Comment: Note that the repeated input code (once for each date) should be in a separate function so that it does not need to be repeated.

Comment: @nimish: It should not fail when the dates are the same; it will return the pointer to the first of the two dates.  We can discuss whether pointers to dates are appropriate as input (why not two separate values, or two separate pointers — it would be a nuisance to have to package up an array just to call this function, even with C99 compound literals), and whether you'd be better off with a date value being returned.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if both the dates are same, It should not return the first date as first date is not coming later than the second. In this code he is returning a pointer to a structure so in case of same dates he can return `0` and check it up in his main function.
For input anything is ok he has cleaned it by using an array of structure simple enough.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Mr Leffler, please point out which `repeated input code` you mean.I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Mr.Leffer, you meant repeated code in my post or the OP's code?

Comment: Both, ultimately.  Granted, you use a loop to get the two dates, but there's a lot of repetition between the code to get the day, the month and the year — with a bit of care, you could reduce your loop body to three calls to the same function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can see what you are trying to tell.But can you give me a clue how to do that?How can the function or loop receive a day in once call/iteration,day in other and year in the last one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Maybe asking the user to enter it all at once in a comma separated format is one way, but that's too simple and relies on the user.So please tell me how to make the same function/loop receive date,year and month.I know they are all integers, but ......

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture I agree with him, I did work on that part in my code i am keeping it straight simple but i don't know if that's the right approach.. Considering the code is too robotic in response and does not involve a human touch like yours ;) :P

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not sure if something like `scanf("%d",&user[i].month+j)` would work where i is an counter.Will it work for a structure element to access the elements this way if they are same type?

Comment: The necessary essay will take a while to write (it'll be an answer, if I actually do it).  Some of the issues are directed at the code in the question as much as your answer.  Making someone enter the date in three separate entries per date is pretty unpleasant; typing 2013-05--03 or 05/03/2013 or 03/05/2013 or something would be better.  However, as written, those loops in the answer have a common structure and similar verbiage and validation.  We can ignore the issue with the 31st of February pro tem, and we could limit years to 1..9999 reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

@Rüppell'sVulture You highlighted his errors but the code is too erroneous. I have worked on a simpler solution of it. Have a look.

@iMPose27 Please see the following code and let me know in case you run in some difficulty

```
// includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// macros
#define NUM 2

// structure Definitions
struct Dates
{
       int month;
       int day;
       int year;
};

// typedefs
typedef struct Dates DATES;

// function declarations
DATES* larger(DATES[NUM]);

// function definitions
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DATES user[NUM];    // array of NUM DATES
    DATES *result=NULL;
    int i=0;
    printf("\nPlease Enter Two Dates, The program will evaluate and return the later date of the two dates passed to it\n\n");
    for(;i<NUM;i++)   
    {    
        printf("For Date %d\n",i+1);

        do{
             printf("Please enter the month, 1-12:\t");
             scanf("%d", &user[i].month);
        }while (user[i].month < 1 || user[i].month > 12);

        do{
              printf("Please enter the day, 1-31:\t");
              scanf("%d", &user[i].day);
        }while (user[i].day < 1 || user[i].day > 31);

        do{           
              printf("Please enter the year: \t");
              scanf("%d)", &user[i].year);
        }while (user[i].year < 1);

        printf("\nDate %d entered: %d/%d/%d.\n\n", i+1, user[i].month, user[i].day, user[i].year);

    } 

    if((result=larger(user))==NULL)
        printf("The two dates passed, date1: %d/%d/%d and date2: %d/%d/%d are the same.\n",user[0].month, user[0].day, user[0].year, user[1].month, user[1].day, user[1].year); 
    else
        printf("%d/%d/%d is the later date of the two dates passed\n",result->month, result->day, result->year); 

    return 0;
}

DATES* larger(DATES more[NUM])
{        
      int days0, days1;

      days0 = (more[0].month*31)+(more[0].day)+(more[0].year*365);
      days1 = (more[1].month*31)+(more[1].day)+(more[1].year*365);

      if (days0 > days1)
        return more;        
      else if (days1 > days0)
        return more+1;
      else
        return 0;       
}
```

Comment: You code doesn't achieve the second objective of the OP's question.Read what he really intends.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Yes true I did not read his question properly. Made the required corrections in the code after referencing yours. Also handled the condition when both the dates are same.

Comment: Date being same is a trivial issue.If you start looking into those, you may very well have to consider things like how come all months have 31 days,what about leap years,what about **BC** as we only consider **AD** here,what happens when the number of years exceed the limit of integers on the computer(After all time  is infinite)  :-)

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture that's true :) concentrated on the least required

Answer (score 0):

As half-promised, a revision of [Rüppell's Vulture](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915076/ruppells-vulture)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16350933/15168).  This code struggles to avoid the repetition in the other answer — which is already reduced by comparison with the code in the question.

There are multiple changes.  Since the type only stores a single date, it is renamed `Date`.  There is a general purpose function `read_validate_number()` which is used to handle the entry of each component of the date (with a separate prompt).  The function returns an error/non-error status and returns the value via a pointer argument.  It puts an upper bound on the number of times the user is prompted for a number.  It avoids insulting the user but does report the erroneous value.  The code uses a `while` loop rather than a `do ... while` loop; generally, the latter should be avoided.  It would be possible to read to a newline after a failure to read a number instead of simply returning an error.

With this function on hand, writing `read_date()` becomes trivial.  And with `read_date()` on hand, the `main()` function simplifies.

I'm still not keen on the interface to the function `larger()`; in general, I prefer the interface shown in `later_date()`.  However, the code shows the one advantage of the `larger()` interface; it can identify the larger of the two dates by position in the array, whereas `later_date()` does that by value.

The functions other than `main()` are static since they aren't used outside this file; the compiler options I use require either `static` functions or an `extern` declaration.

On the whole, I'd prefer a less verbose interface for entering dates.  I also prefer the ISO 8601 format for dates since they are unambiguous; however, that would be a user preference item in fully internationalized (and localized) code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define NUM 2
typedef struct Date
{
       int month;
       int day;
       int year;
} Date;

enum { MAX_ERRORS = 3 };

static int read_validate_number(const char *tag, int min, int max, int *value)
{
    int errors = 0;
    assert(min <= max);
    while (errors++ < MAX_ERRORS)
    {
        printf("Please enter the %s number (%d-%d): ", tag, min, max);
        if (scanf("%d", value) != 1)
        {
            printf("Failed to read number\n");
            return EOF;
        }
        if (*value >= min && *value <= max)
            return 0;
        printf("The value entered (%d) is outside the range %d-%d\n", *value, min, max);
    }
    printf("Too many errors entering %s\n", tag);
    return EOF;
}

static int read_date(Date *date)
{
    if (read_validate_number("month", 1,   12, &date->month) != 0 ||
        read_validate_number("day",   1,   31, &date->day  ) != 0 ||
        read_validate_number("year",  1, 9999, &date->year ) != 0)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

static Date *larger(Date *more)
{
    int days0 = (more[0].month*31)+(more[0].day)+(more[0].year*365);
    int days1 = (more[1].month*31)+(more[1].day)+(more[1].year*365);

    // Resist the temptation to write: return more + (days1 > days0);
    if (days1 > days0)
        return more+1;
    else
        return more+0;
}

static Date later_date(Date d1, Date d2)
{
    int days1 = d1.day + d1.month * 31 + d1.year * 365;
    int days2 = d2.day + d2.month * 31 + d2.year * 365;

    if (days1 > days2)
        return d1;
    else
        return d2;
}

int main(void)
{
    Date user[NUM];

    printf("Enter two dates, and the program will return the larger.\n");
    if (read_date(&user[0]) == 0 && read_date(&user[1]) == 0)
    {
        putchar('\n');
        printf("Date 1: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", user[0].year, user[0].month, user[0].day);
        printf("Date 2: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", user[1].year, user[1].month, user[1].day);
        Date *p_later = larger(user);
        Date  v_later = later_date(user[0], user[1]);
        printf("\nThe later date is the %s (%d/%d/%d)\n",
               (p_later == &user[0]) ? "first" : "second",
               p_later->month, p_later->day, p_later->year);
        printf("Later Date: %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", v_later.year, v_later.month, v_later.day);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter two dates, and the program will return the larger.
Please enter the month number (1-12): 12
Please enter the day number (1-31): 25
Please enter the year number (1-9999): 2013
Please enter the month number (1-12): 1
Please enter the day number (1-31): 1
Please enter the year number (1-9999): 2012

Date 1: 2013-12-25
Date 2: 2012-01-01

The later date is the first (12/25/2013)
Later Date: 2013-12-25
```

I note that you could reduce the size of the `Date` structure by using `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) for the `day` and `month` components, and an `unsigned short` (or `uint16_t`) for the `year` component.  However, you'd have to modify the `read_date()` function a bit to do so:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Date
{
       uint8_t  month;
       uint8_t  day;
       uint16_t year;
} Date;

static int read_date(Date *date)
{
    int mm, dd, yyyy;
    if (read_validate_number("month", 1,   12, &mm  ) != 0 ||
        read_validate_number("day",   1,   31, &dd  ) != 0 ||
        read_validate_number("year",  1, 9999, &yyyy) != 0)
        return EOF;
    date->month = mm;
    date->day   = dd;
    date->year  = yyyy;
    return 0;
}
```

At some point, you might want to prevent someone entering the 31st of February (but remember that there was once a [30th of February](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30) — in Sweden, in 1712; or there again, maybe you don't need to remember that).