# C infinite do while loop

Tags: c, loops, scanf, do-while, infinite

This is a simple program for a class that prompts the user for the length of his or her shower in minutes (as a positive integer, re-prompting as needed) and then prints the equivalent number of bottles of water (as an integer).

It assumes the shower uses 1.5 gallons of water per minute (192 oz) and a plastic bottle size of 16 oz

My do-while loop successfully rejects negative numbers and 0, however, if I input text such as "foo" when prompted for the length of a shower in minutes, the program runs into an infinite loop, forever running the loop and printing "How long is your shower(in minutes)?:"

Any ideas how to refine the while condition to avoid this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min_to_bottles(int *n);

int main(void)
{
    int minutes;
    int bottles;
    do
    {
        printf("How long is your shower(in minutes)?:");
        scanf("%i", &minutes);
    }
    while (minutes < 1);

    bottles = min_to_bottles(&minutes);

    printf("Equivalent of bottles used per shower is: %i\n", bottles);

}

int min_to_bottles(int *n)
{
    int bottles;
    int oz = 192 * *n;
    bottles = oz/16;
    return bottles;
}
```

Comment: `while ((scanf("%d", &minutes) == 1) && (minutes < 1));`! There is a return value for `scanf()` just use it. This will not fix the problem, you still can have minutes wrong so set it to `-1` initially and check after the `while` loop to ensure it's correct.

Comment: @iharob but why isn't scanf blocking after the first incorrect input?

Comment: How do you know it's infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always check the return value of `scanf()`:

```
int result;
do {
    printf("How long is your shower(in minutes)?:");
    result = scanf("%d", &minutes);
    if(result != 1) 
        break;
} while (minutes < 1);
```

A shorter version (if only one scan is needed):

```
printf("How long is your shower(in minutes)?:");

while ((scanf("%d", &minutes) == 1) && (minutes < 1))
    ;
```

---

There is no need to use a pointer as parameter in `int min_to_bottles(int *n);`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min_to_bottles(int n)
{
    return (192 * n) / 16;
}

int main(void)
{
    int minutes = 0;
    int bottles = 0;

    printf("How long is your shower(in minutes)?: ");

    while ((scanf("%d", &minutes) == 1) && (minutes < 1 || minutes > 100))
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 100 : ");

    // if(minutes == 0) here means invalid data was entered.
    //    so a check could be done before continuing.

    bottles = min_to_bottles(minutes);

    printf("Equivalent of bottles used per shower is: %d\n", bottles);

    return 0;
}
```

Initializing `minutes` to `0` will avoid calculating the `bottles` with an undefined value in case `scanf()` failed (by entering text for example).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still quite the beginner with C, I appreciate any answer that helps me to better understand all the lower level aspects of programming.

Comment: @TomasVrba - Glad to help. Don't hesitate to ask, and enjoy your C-journey!

Answer (score 1):

When you enter in text, it doesn't match the `%i` format specifier, so the text gets stuck in the input buffer and it keeps trying to read the same thing.

You need to flush the buffer if you didn't get a good match.  You'll know if that the case by checking the return value of `scanf`, which returns the number of patters successfully matched.

```
int minutes = 0;
while (minutes < 1)
{
    printf("How long is your shower(in minutes)?:");
    int count = scanf("%i", &minutes);
    if (count < 1) {
        scanf("%*s");   // The * tells scanf to read the input but not assign it to anything
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `scanf("%i",...)`.

The main problem is that bad input that did not convert to a number *remains* in `stdin` until another function reads it.  As code did not check the return value of `scanf()`, the value of `minutes` is not known to be good and `do ... while (minutes < 1);` can easily repeated loop.

Solution: Read a line of input, convert to number, valid number:

---

To handle unexpected user input begin by reading a line of input

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
```

Then parse the buffer for the number.

```
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
long num == strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);

// detect overflow and no conversiosn
if (errno || buf == endptr) Handle_BadInput();

// Ignore trailing white-space
while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr) endptr++;

if (*endptr) Handle_BadInput();
```

Validate the number.

```
#define SHOWER_TIME_MIN (1 /* minute */)
#define SHOWER_TIME_MAX (60 /* minute */)
if (num < SHOWER_TIME_MIN || num > SHOWER_TIME_MAX) Handle_BadInput();
```

Put this all in a helper function

Example [How to test input is sane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20269225/2410359)