# Get a little help to my program: infinite loop in the scanf

Tags: c

my programe gets 5 grades and calculates average and max values.but when i enter a letter first instead of a grade, it continuously prints "invalid". when i enter a letter after entering a int value it stops further getting remaining values.can someone explain where i am wrong? thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int grade[5];
    int temp;
    int temp2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) //getting inputs
    {
        printf("enter grade= ");
        scanf("%i", &temp);
        if(temp <= 100 && temp >= 0)
            grade[i] = temp;
        else
        {
            printf("invalid\n");
            i--;
        }
    }

    //print array
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        printf("%i\n", grade[i]);

    //Average
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2 + grade[i];
    }

    printf("avg is= %i\n", temp2 / 5);

    //Max
    int mx = grade[0];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        if(mx < grade[i])
        {
            mx = grade[i];
        }
    printf("max is= %i", mx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your grades are integer, why are you entering a letter as input?

Comment: You should provide a more meaningfull title if you wish to receive more help. Not a C developer but it seems to me that you have to check your input before processing it

Comment: characters interpreted as ASCII values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `scanf` man page:

```
These functions return the number of input items successfully
matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or
even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
```

So when the scan fails, you have to read and throw the offending characters, or it will still be in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following macro instead of using `scanf()` directelly

```
#define SCAN_ONEENTRY_WITHCHECK(FORM,X,COND) \
do {\
    char tmp;\
    while(((scanf(" "FORM"%c",X,&tmp)!=2 || !isspace(tmp)) && !scanf("%*[^\n]"))\
            || !(COND)) {\
        printf("Invalid input, please enter again: ");\
    }\
} while(0)
```

and in your code you call the macro in this way

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) //getting inputs
{
    printf("enter grade= ");
    SCAN_ONEENTRY_WITHCHECK("%i",&tmp,(temp <= 100 && temp >= 0));
    grade[i] = temp;
}
```

for more details concerning the macro and concerning the reason of getting infinite loop in your code, please refer to [Common macro to read input data and check its validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792984/common-macro-to-read-input-data-and-check-its-validity)